# Angular 7 - Emitter and Poller (called twice)

Tags: angular

I'm having a problem with event-emitter and Poller.

In my Filtering component I have:

```
ngOnInit() 
{
    this.map_ready_subscription = this._eventEmitterService.map_ready.subscribe(value => this.firstSearch());
    this.poller_source    = interval(60000); //refreshing map every 1 minute
    this.poller_subscribe = this.poller_source.subscribe(val =>  this.applyFilter());
}

firstSearch()
{
  this.map_ready_subscription.unsubscribe();
  this.applyFilter();
}
```

map_ready is emitted in another component with "true" value. When Map Component is ready, I can launch first search with default filter value.

As you seen from code, I then create a **Poller** to refresh filter every 60 seconds.

In my frontend, I have a form for filter value change. On Click I call **applyFilter**.

The problem is the poller.
After one minute, **applyFilter** is called twice every time. One with the "firstSearch" params and the second one with the current filter values.

As you see, I've tried to unsubscribe from emitter during first search but it doesn't work.
I've added an unsubscribe in onDestroy too:

```
ngOnDestroy() 
  {
    if (this.poller_subscribe !== undefined)
    {
      this.poller_subscribe.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
```

Any clues?

Comment: You say that applyFilter is called twice with different params, but in your code fragments, applyFilter is called without parameters?

Comment: Parameters are local variables of component used by form component with ngModel